# Protect electrical wiring between drywall and brick fireplace

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety, fireplace

Following the question at [Frame drywall around brick fireplace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/148172/frame-drywall-around-brick-fireplace) I would like to figure out how to protect the electrical wiring and other wirings (HDMI) from the top down in middle of the fireplace as outlet for my TV:

[image]

Do I need heat protection wiring conduit / shield? Which type do people usually use?

Comment: Is your fireplace a gas burner, or a solid fuel burner? What's its clearance-to-combustibles rating?

Comment: One gas and one wood (which I won't ever use). But I think there is 2" air gap clearance in general. Regardless, I think there gotta be a way to shield it from the heat?

Comment: Err, I meant *this particular fireplace* -- I take it the other fireplace is somewhere else on its own flue system?

Comment: If you're running the wire down against the cinder-blocks, it will be fine. If you're really concerned that heat may affect the wires (which it shouldn't) then I would strap 1/2" SCH-40 PVC to the brick running into a box (pvc or metal). The bricks surrounding the flue don't really get warm enough to affect current flow in the wire, certainly not warm enough to damage the wire. The flue does a pretty good job keeping the heat inside.